# linux mount nfs based on wifi network name

Tags: wireless-networking, fedora

I'm running fedora 17 with gnome3 and NetworkManager. I have a script "mountNFS.sh" which mounts the NFS exports from my NAS at home. I want know a way to automatically mount and umount my NFS storages when I connect and disconnect from my home wifi. My home wifi has a unique name.